# setCurrentItem after setting adapter on GridViewPager return NPE

Tags: android, wear-os

does anyone knows a better solution then waiting for a few milliseconds if you try to start with a given item on a GridViewPager in Android Wear like this one:

```
pager.setAdapter(new MainGridAdapter(this, getFragmentManager()));
Runnable dirtyHack = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        pager.setCurrentItem(2, 0);
    }
};
Handler handler = new Handler();
handler.postDelayed(dirtyHack, 100);
```

The issue is described [here](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=75309) and I ran also into it